# SQL Server query with different date conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a column where condition is `Target_L * X / Y`.

Where need x and y should automatically come from a query.

- Y = Total Number of working days in month, excluding Sunday
  i.e for Jan, 27 days are working days
- X = Working days till yesterday's date
  i.e 23 (Minus Sunday, 1 to 26 = 26-3=23)

Today is 27 January 2018

final = Target_L * 23/27

OR

If this is long approach this second one is also OK

- There is a second approach also
  ,X= Total working days i.e 31 for January Including Sunday
  Y=till date working days Including Sunday
  26/31

From both Any approach is Good for me,I need q query for this ..I have date column,Month column.
Using SQL SERVER

Comment: In the United, there were 21 working days in January (Jan 1 and Jan 15 were holidays, plus the two day weekends).  In other words, what you are asking is culture specific and you should have a calendar table if you want to maintain this kind of information.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Yes I have calender Table also..Let assume that there are 3 Government Holiday then what would be approach

Comment: But we need the sales for holidays also except sunday's as we are open for all days specially on Public holiday

Comment: and I have not done any approach for this ..It would be good if you tell me the approach as i am too weak in Date query part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. But try this.

```
DECLARE @FirstDay DATETIME
SET @FirstDay = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

DECLARE @LastDay DATETIME
SET @LastDay = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) 

DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME
SET @Yesterday = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)


DECLARE @DaysInMonth int
SET @DaysInMonth = DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE()))

DECLARE @NoOFSundaysInMonth int
SET @NoOFSundaysInMonth = DATEDIFF(WK, DAteAdd(DD, -1,@FirstDay), DAteAdd(DD, 1, @LastDay)) 

DECLARE @NoOfDaysWithoutSunInMonth int
SET @NoOfDaysWithoutSunInMonth = @DaysInMonth - @NoOFSundaysInMonth


DECLARE @NoOFDaysTillYes int
SET @NoOFDaysTillYes = DATEDIFF(d, @FirstDay, GETDATE())

DECLARE @NoOFSunTillYes int
SET @NoOFSunTillYes = DATEDIFF(WK, DAteAdd(DD, -1,@FirstDay), DAteAdd(DD, 1, @Yesterday)) 

DECLARE @NoOfDaysWithoutSunTillYes int
SET @NoOfDaysWithoutSunTillYes = @NoOFDaysTillYes - @NoOFSunTillYes
```

To check these values, add this to query

```
SELECT
@FirstDay AS 'First_Day', 
@LastDay AS 'Last_Day', 
@Yesterday AS 'Yesterday',

@DaysInMonth AS 'Days_In_Month', 
@NoOFSundaysInMonth AS 'No_Of_Sundays', 
@NoOfDaysWithoutSunInMonth AS 'No_OF_Days_Without_Sun',

@NoOFDaysTillYes AS 'No_OF_Days_Till_Yesterday',
@NoOFSunTillYes AS 'No_OF_Sundays_Till_Yesterday',
@NoOfDaysWithoutSunTillYes AS 'No_OF_Days_Without_Sunday_Till_Yesterday'
```

If 'Y' means total all the days in this month without Sundays and if 'X' means all days without Sundays until yesterday, you can use this.

```
final =Target_L * X/Y
```

```
final =Target_L * @NoOfDaysWithoutSunTillYes / @NoOfDaysWithoutSunInMonth
```

NoOfDaysWithoutSunTillYes = 23
NoOfDaysWithoutSunInMonth = 27

Comment: @nicomp Appreciate ..What If i want to make a calendar table and I will put all the holiday entry into that ..then how will  I approach